# Show a certain sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $s$ satisfy: $0<s<1$. Show that $ns^{n-1}$ is bounded $\forall n\ge1$.

Thoughts so far:

If we can treat the $ns^{n-1}$ as a sequence and show it is convergent, it is easy to show it is bounded. For whatever reason, this seemingly simple task is tripping me up today. I've tried L'Hospital's 0/0 Case since you can rewrite the proposed sequence in such a form but received no helpful insight from that. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to show that $\{ns^{n-1}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded for each fixed $s$, or that $ns^{n-1}$, $0<s<1$ is bounded for each $n$?

Comment: @carmichael561 I am trying to prove the latter.

Comment: Well, if $0<s<1$ then $0<s^{n-1}<1$, so there's not much to show.

Comment: Do you mean that I can simply multiply that second inequality by n? and have it bounded by 0 and n?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=nx^{n-1}$, $\forall x\in (0,1]$
We have $$f'(x)=n(n-1)x^{n-2}>0 \forall n\ge1$$
Thus $f$ is strictly increasing in $(0,1]$ and $f(1)>f(x) \forall x\in (0,1)$

So your bound is equal to $f(1)=n$.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I am looking for. However, shouldn't it be that f'(x)>=0? Since f'(x) = 0 when n=1?

Comment: @EthanZell Glad I helped! Well, for $n=1$ you can argue that it is a "trivial" case since you get $ns^{n-1}=s^0=1$ which is obviously bounded as a constant.